# bootstrap typeahead with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not able to get typeahead to work on my website, here what I have tried.

My html and code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>typeahead</title>

     <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<input id="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
  source: function (query, process) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      async: true,
      data: 'query=' + query,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        process(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

when I query data.php in my browser, I get the following

```
http://localhost/data.php?query=a
```

output

```
["admin","admin2"]
```

Yet, I'm not sure why its not working, backend works, I have checked my code many times, I wonder what I'm missing.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.php', // Just try url:'data.php?query=a'
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  async: true,
  data: {'query' : query}, // changed
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     process(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: If this is not working just remove the line dataType: 'JSON' and chaeck

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, but its still not working, any other troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Please use the browser utility for tracking the Ajax request. Chrome is recommended

Answer (score 0):

You can write you ajax call like this with Bootstrap 2.1.0 up to 2.3.2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (typeahead, query) {
                return $.get('data.php', { 'query': a }, function (data) {
                    return typeahead.process(data);
                });
            }
        });

});
```

with Bootstrap 3.0 type is no longer bundled with it, So you can use [Ajax Type-ahead](https://github.com/pwarelis/Ajax-Typeahead)

its very easy to use:

```
$("#ajax-typeahead").typeahead({
     ajax: "/path/to/source"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically typeahead uses handlebar.js as well so I included that here.  I updated your code to match the remote example [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote) (though I didn't actually test the code).  Hopefully that will get you pointed in the right direction.

```
<html>
<head>
        <title>typeahead</title>

         <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.4/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="typeahead" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mySearch = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            prefetch: 'data.php',
            remote: 'data.php?query=' + query
        });

        mySearch.initialize();

        $('#typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'best-pictures',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: mySearch.ttAdapter()
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```